# Read and write unicode from file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

I have a unicode string ® in a file. I want to read it with Python, convert it to bits, then back to unicode and write into a new file.
It works if I make a variable `test_unicode = "®"` and work with it. But if I read this ® from a file - I get some random stuff (tried errors=replace, backslashreplace, ignore). Here is my script:

```
def frombits(bits):
    chars = []
    for b in range(int(len(bits) / 8)):
        byte = bits[b*8:(b+1)*8]
        chars.append(chr(int(''.join([str(bit) for bit in byte]), 2)))
    return ''.join(chars)

bit_list = ''
with open('uni.txt', "r", encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while(byte):
        bit_list+='{0:08b}'.format(ord(byte))
        byte=f.read(1)

test_unicode = '®'
test_unicode_bit_list = '{0:08b}'.format(ord(test_unicode))

print(bit_list)
print(test_unicode_bit_list)

test_unicode = ''.join(frombits(test_unicode_bit_list))
read_unicode = ''.join(frombits(bit_list))

print(test_unicode.encode("utf-8"))
print(read_unicode.encode("utf-8"))

f = open("uni_test.txt", 'wb')
f.write(test_unicode.encode("utf-8"))
f = open("uni_read.txt", 'wb')
f.write(read_unicode.encode("utf-8"))
```

If I make a file uni.txt with ® inside and run this script the end I get 2 files (first was made using the variable test_unicode and second one using the value read from uni.txt):

uni_test.txt ---> ®

uni_read.txt ---> ÿý

How do I do this "read - convert to bits - convert to unicode - write" procedure correctly? Thank you!

Comment: open your file for read in bytes using `open(filename, 'rb')` and then save it with the appropriate encoding

Comment: I will post this as an answer so you can accept and close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your file for read in bytes using `open(filename, 'rb')` and then save it with the appropriate encoding